# Need page title and toggle button on the same line in extra small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap navigation bar in the top which has a quite long title and a toggle button to show collapsed links in small devices.
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Yet Another Bootstrap Navigation </a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button>
                </div>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>


</html>
```

But in extra small devices the button comes down because this title is quite large.[image]

Is there ant way to keep those on same line like the previous state?

Comment: in which device. share me the width to reproduce your issue

Comment: device with extra small screen mean the screens which has less  than 768px.

Comment: You can use a css rule with media query to reduce `font-size` of the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try This CSS Code

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{padding-right: 70px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle{position: absolute;right: 0;}
```